# How do I execute SQL commands using a batch (.bat) file without accessing external SQL?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

Is it possible to execute SQL commands written in a batch (.bat) file without accessing an external SQL script file. How can I do that? I don't want to call an external sql because i want to require as input a month, then execute the sql command that contains that month in some queries.

Comment: Calling one batch file(has sql cmds) from other batch file(has command to call master batch file).

Comment: Based on a comment you made on one of the answers, how do you plan on compiling this to an exe?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you want this put on another computer? What is this FOR?

Comment: http://www.battoexeconverter.com/

Comment: well there is an invoice software based on sql that i distribute, some people want to change their price on they articles pricetag because they know the price at the end of the month, and extend the changes of this price on their invoices at the end of the month before of emitting them, actually for doing this on that program users must enter on every invoice they have made and change the prices manually, with this little program they only change the pricetag on the article then, they run the batch and this batch changes the price of the articles on the invoices taking it from the pricetag.

Comment: and the month is because they do this at the end of the month , or the next month for the previous month, because of invoices are made at the end of months in this case...

Comment: Have a table where you store future price changes and allow them to add entries to that table. Then have a stored procedure to apply the changes to the live price table when the date comes.

Answer (score 2):

Asuume you have 3 files in your folder.
file **1** => .sql file
file **2** => mybatchfile1.bat(which has sqlcmds or cmd to execute the above .sql file)
file **3** => one other batch file(myexecute.bat) to call the above batch file(which has content "start mybatchfile1.bat")

All you need to create is **myexecute.bat** with the below content:

```
start mybatchfile1.bat
```

or

```
call mybatchfile1.bat
```

You can use either start or call.

Comment: Ok, but nextly I want to compile this batch as an exe,and put this exe in another computer without bringing me back the sql file, to make impossible to read the sql commands from external users

Comment: Please don't tell me that i have to hide somewhere in that computer a *.sql file that is going to be called from my batch, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Recomend on using powershell script:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery;" -ServerInstance "SERVER\Instance" -Password "Password"
```

the output will be orginized as a Table and it's far more easy then bat file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run a query from a single DOS batch script, getting input from command line parameters and/or user prompts, rather easily. SQLCMD allows for passing in a query on the command line. By the very nature of passing something into a program from the command line, you can just place the DOS variable wherever you want it to go.

Place the following into a script with an extension of `.cmd` (you should not be using the `.bat` extension unless you have a specific need for something to run in a 16-bit process):

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO.
SET /P Month="Please enter in a month: "
ECHO.

ECHO.
ECHO Month = %Month%
ECHO.

SET Month=%Month:'=%
ECHO Month with single-quotes removed = %Month%
ECHO.

SQLCMD.EXE -E -Q "IF (COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(TINYINT, REPLACE('%Month%', '''', '''''')), 0) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12) BEGIN RAISERROR('Please enter a value 1 - 12.', 16, 1); RETURN; END; SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, '2014-%Month%-01') AS [MonthName];"
```

Run it without passing in any parameters. It will prompt for the month. It will then substitute that value in the query, which does its own data validation on the input.

**NOTE:** be sure to validate input to protect against SQL Injection. The above example replaces single-quotes with escaped-single-quotes for this reason. It also removes all single-quotes before the variable is even used in the query so the `REPLACE()` is just a redundant safety.

```
C:\>.\SingleScriptToAcceptParamForQuery.cmd

Please enter in a month: '5

Month = '5

Month with single-quotes removed = 5

MonthName
------------------------------
May

(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: DANGER Will Robinson! SQLI!

Comment: @Ben , uh no. It can be validated rather easily. This is just an example. No reason to -1 when this actually works.

Comment: @Ben : I updated with protection against SQL Injection. Please remove the downvote.